# Google Apps Script - how to copy data from one sheet to another based on the max limit of a group

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

1st sheet name = Source;

Columns in 1st sheet = Name, Projects, Status;

2nd sheet name = Volume;

Columns in 2nd sheet = Name, Max number of Projects;

3rd sheet name = Target;

Columns in 3rd sheet = Name, Projects, Status;

I am very new in Google Apps Script and I need your help here. We have our input data in the source sheet and in the volume sheet, Manager can provide the name and the max number of projects the person can work on. Based on that, the resultant data will get pasted in the Target sheet.

Means for name ‘abc’ if the number of projects listed for ‘abc’ is 10 in Source sheet but in the volume sheet if ‘abc’ is has been assigned with only 6 projects, then in the target sheet abc will get only 6 projects.

I am very new in Google Apps Script and I am unable to understand how can I do that.

Please assist!!

Comment: Google apps script is just plain javascript. Check this link to help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Comment: _then in the target sheet abc will get only 6 projects._ It should be six first projects? The script must ignore the rest four projects?

Comment: @yuri - yes, it should be the first 6 projects. The script can ignore the remaining projects for abc. I am very new to JS and Google Apps Script. Kindly help!!

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: Well. I removed my answer, since there is no reaction from the asker.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help??

Comment: @YuriKhristich- Hi Yuri, the code which you shared works perfectly fine with only 2 tasks alloted in Volume. It fails to work with any other number of allotment. Can you please help??? Apologies for the delay. I was unwell for few weeks.